# MouseListener and HTML5 canvas object

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have been looking at tutorials and yet I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.  This seems like it should be very straight forward yet it's giving me problems.    Below is some simple code for creating a mouse listener for a canvas object.  Currently function clickReporter is not being called when the canvas is clicked.  Any ideas on why not?

HTML5

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Play Area 2 - Mouse Events and the Canvas</title>
    <script src="play_area_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init();">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400">
    Your browser dosen't support the HTML5 canvas.</canvas><br />
    </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript

```
    var canvas;
    var context;

    function init() {
        canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        drawBox();

        canvas.addEventListener('onclick', clickReporter, false);
    }

    function clickReporter(e) {
        alert("clicked");
    }

    function drawBox() {
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.strokeRect(20, 20, canvas.width-20, canvas.height-20);
    }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be using 'click' and not 'onclick'.  "on" is only used when setting it as a property (e.g., canvas.onclick = clickReporter).

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', clickReporter, false);
```

**UPDATE**

More details on click vs. onclick.

There are three ways to attach an event listener to an object in JavaScript:

1. Through *element*.addEventListener.  When you use this, you specify the event name you want to set.  For example, 'click', or 'mouseover', or 'touchstart'.  In this case, you're specifying the event's actual name.  This is useful because you can add more than one listener to an event.

   ```
   canvas.addEventListener('click', clickReporter, false);
   canvas.addEventListener('click', otherClickReporter, false);
   // Both clickReporter and otherClickReporter will be called on a click event.
   ```
2. Through *element*.onsomeevent (onclick, onmouseover, ontouchstart).  This is an older convention which is fully standard and supported in HTML5.  This is a very easy way to set the event listener but it has its drawbacks.  Only one event listener can be set at a time with this method:

   ```
   canvas.onclick = clickReporter;
   canvas.onclick = otherClickReporter;
   // Only otherClickReporter will be called on a click event.
   ```
3. Through the HTML itself.  This is where all the conventions started.  You can define an event directly in the HTML very much like the previous example:

   ```
   <canvas onclick="clickReporter()"></canvas>
   ```

   This is the same as the following, assuming that clickReporter gets attached to the window object.

   ```
   <canvas></canvas>
   <script>
       canvasWeJustCreated.onclick = function() {clickReporter();}
   </script>
   ```

Arguably the way you are doing it is the best way.  There will certainly be cases where you want to use the other methods, like when generating a page on the server or trying to temporarily suppress scrolling on an iPhone, but for most applications, addEventListener is best.

Comment: Wow. Thanks, I was using an example from w3schools.com and must have looked at the wrong exampile code.  If you don't mind, could you explain a bit more about what you mean by 'onclick' only being for a property is the actual action no the same thing, why is it different?

Comment: I've added a comparison of different methods above.  As to why addEventListener doesn't use 'on', its strictly convention.

Comment: Again, thank you that was very informative.  I am just now trying to learn java script and my back ground is in Java and C so it's been a bit of a hassle trying to get a hang of it.

Comment: Uhm, the Only one event will be called is true with IE's event model. jQuery can handle more than one for all browsers, as I recall. Also, you can use the power of event bubbling and attach it to the parent or any other for that matter, you do not /need/ to set an ID to have an event handler. So, in my example you can use $('#canvasZone').on('click potato','canvas',function(event){ $(this).css('color','red'); }); That will basically attach an event handler to #canvasZone, but will be triggering handler when clicking on the canvas element, OR if you $('body').trigger('potato');

Comment: @renoirb It is true that old IE (5, 6, don't remember) didn't support multiple event binding, but more recent did via `attachEvent` and current does via the standard.  It is moot for this problem, however, because every browser that supports `<canvas>` supports `addEventListener`.  Given that jQuery provides zero benefit for canvas rendering, it is an expensive dependency to bring in.